# How to pass user information to Commerce product fields when creating a product?

Tags: commerce, entities

Looking for a way to pass user information and other ready-filled product information to the fields when creating a new product.

More precisely, I'm working with multiple type CVs as Commerce products and it's definitely a stretch to have the users type in lots and lots of the same information over and over again.

Hence, I'd like as much information as possible to be passed from the users own profile (e.g. name, address, etc.) and from CVs that the user has filled out already (competences, personal qualities, etc.). Bare in mind, these should definitely be multistep (multipage) content anyways but multistep only apparently works with normal content types and not with Commerces product types. Please correct me if I'm wrong. The point is to make adding products as easy as possible :)

Comment: Have you considered adding a user reference field to do this instead of repeating information?

Comment: No but I will, thank you! But if I got this right, this still won't solve my problem with passing information from other than user data fields...